# How can I format a new internal hard drive in my Macbook Pro Mid-2012 13" if it keeps getting stuck at "Waiting for disks to repair"?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, formatting, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro Mid-2012 13" that I recently replaced the internal hard drive in. I replaced the stock hard drive with a 240GB SSD from Crucial. I am trying to install OS X El Capitan with a bootable drive that I already made. I start the mac in safe mode, then open disk utility. When I attempt to format (OS X Extended(Journaled)) the new SSD by erasing it, it says:

Unmounting disk

Creating the partition map

Waiting for the disks to reappear

However when it reaches the "Waiting for the disks to reappear" it never continues and there is no progress in the progress bar.

Thanks!